# Created element is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to create a html5 video volume manipulation, and I want to insert it into the `DOM` using javascript, but when I browse over the element using `for` loop, it returns `undefined`. 
This is my code:

```
    // Volume
    var volumeWrapper = document.createElement('span');
    volumeWrapper.className = "volumeWrapper";
    insertAfter(elapseTimeWrapper, volumeWrapper);

    for ( var i = 0; i <= 4; i ++ ) {
        var volumeControl = document.createElement('span');
        volumeWrapper.appendChild(volumeControl);
        (function(index) {
            volumeControl.onclick = function() {
                if ( this.className == "" ) {
                    this.className = "active";
                    for ( var j = 0; j <= index; j ++ ) {
                        console.log(volumeControl[j]) // return undefined
                    }
                } else {
                    this.className = "";
                }
            }
        })(i);
    }
```

I don't know what's wrong with this code, when I insert it directly into html, it's not `undefined`. It returns the exact value of the elments. I want to insert it using javascript not html. I need your help.
Thank you in advanced for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your code is incorrect.

Here is something that might help you:

```
  var volumeControl = [];
  for ( var i = 0; i <= 4; i++ ) {
        volumeControl[i] = document.createElement('button');
        volumeControl[i].innerHTML = i;
        volumeControl[i].id = "b" + i;
        volumeWrapper.appendChild(volumeControl[i]);
        (function(index) {
            volumeControl[i].onclick = function() {
                if ( this.className == "" ) {
                    this.className = "active";
                    console.log(volumeControl[index].id); // return undefined
                } else {
                    this.className = "";
                }
            }
        })(i);
    }
```

I replace `span` by `button` so that you can understand more easily what is going on. When you click a button, it displays the id of the clicked button. Of course, this code does not what you want, but the code structure should help you.

Additionnally, `insertAfter`at the beginning of your code is not correct.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I didn't think about adding an ID to my code. Your code runs perfectly! :D